# A string of binary number from a string of its decimal

Tags: java, string, binary, decimal, biginteger

Here is what i am trying to do, I have a string of decimal number like this : `String s="55795556555.....",`
I want to convert it to byte array:

```
byte[] array=s.getbyte(),
```

Then pass that byte array to a BigInteger:

```
BigInteger number=new BigInteger(array),
```

Then convert it to binary string:

```
String str=number.toString(2),
```

I got the wrong binary representation... Why? And how to fix it?

Comment: Did you check that the value of the BigInteger was correct?

Answer (score 0):

### [`BigInteger#BigInteger(java.lang.String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(java.lang.String))

Do it as follows:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "55795556555123";
        BigInteger number = new BigInteger(s);
        System.out.println(number.toString(2));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1100101011111011101010010101000001100101110011
```

If you want to get it from `byte[]`, you can do it as follows by using [`String#String(byte[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte%5B%5D)):

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "55795556555123";
        byte[] array = s.getBytes();
        BigInteger number = new BigInteger(new String(array));
        System.out.println(number.toString(2));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1100101011111011101010010101000001100101110011
```

Comment: BigInteger(String s) take so long if the number is so big (1 billion digits)... While if i pass a byte array of one billion element it will take few hours to be done... This is why i want a solution for my approach

Comment: @jhamine - What is your use case for 1 billion digits?

Answer (score 0):

You've entirely misunderstood what [`new BigInteger(array)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-byte:A-) does. As the javadoc says:

> Translates a byte array containing the **two's-complement binary representation** of a BigInteger into a BigInteger. The input array is assumed to be in *big-endian* byte-order: the most significant byte is in the zeroth element.

Say your string is `s = "123456". That is hex` 1E240`, which means that the` byte[]`you pass to the`BigInteger` constructor should be:

```java
byte[] array = { 0x01, (byte) 0xE2, 0x40 };
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)); // prints: [1, -30, 64]

BigInteger number = new BigInteger(array);
System.out.println(number); // prints: 123456
```

But javadoc of `s.getBytes()` *(not `getbyte()`)* says:

> returns a sequence of bytes using the platform's **default charset**

Which in this case generally means in [**ASCII**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

```java
String s = "123456";
byte[] array = s.getBytes();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)); // prints: [49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54]
```

As you can see, that `byte[]` is nowhere near what is should be for that `BigInteger` constructor.

You have to call [`new BigInteger(s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-java.lang.String-). I doubt you can write a faster version of `String` (with decimal number text) to `byte[]` (two's-complement binary) conversion.

Comment: Exactly... This is what i am trying to do... I just want to know if someone did found how to write a faster version of string to byte[] (two's-complement binary) conversion before i start atacking the problem by myself... You've got no idea how great would that be...

Comment: @jhamine If that's what you want to know, why didn't you ask that in the question? The question is asking something entirely different. Go ahead, read your own question to check for yourself. It only asks how to fix the code, and got 2 answers saying "use `BigInteger(String)` constructor". There is nothing in the question about speed, or why you didn't try to use that constructor yourself. Besides, what makes you think it *can* be done faster? Why do you believe that the `BigInteger` constructor isn't already optimized?

Comment: it's not that i dont beleiveve that the BigInteger constructor isn't already optimized, i am only saying that the level of optimization of the constructor is not enough for me... Passing string with 1 billion caractere to BigInteger take for ever... It must be a better way... peoples may not given it enough efford to established it because they dont need it... Come on.. Who plays with 1 billion  number digits!!

Comment: @jhamine if you really need to create such a large BigInteger faster, from a constant value, you could create it once and then convert it to a byte array with the `toByteArray()` method or even serialize it, and then regenerating it from that array or the serialized form will probably be faster.

Comment: @jhamine *"It must be a better way"* Wishing it so doesn't make it so. --- But let us take a step back, and consider if this is perhaps an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/351454). *Why* do you want a `BigInteger` object for a number with 1 billion digits? What's the point? What are you going to do with it? Which is basically what [Arvind already asked you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64828030/a-string-of-binary-number-from-a-string-of-its-decimal/64828628?noredirect=1#comment114619044_64828052), and you never responded: "What is your use case for 1 billion digits?"